# Alias is already in use by the "--collection" option and cannot be used by the "--change-detection" option

Tags: angular, npm, alias

Environment:

- Ubuntu 16.04
- Angular CLI 1.7.3

I'm getting the error by executing **ng generate component dashboard**, but it also happens with **ng generate c**

```
$ ng generate component dashboard
The "c" alias is already in use by the "--collection" option 
and cannot be used by the "--change-detection" option.
Please use a different alias.
```

I tried to look for an error in npm, ant I got the following error

```
$npm list
...
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular-devkit/core@0.4.5, required by @schematics/angular@0.4.5
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular-devkit/schematics@0.4.5, required by @schematics/angular@0.4.5
```

It looks something related with npm validate alias

**[function angular-cli.command.prototype.validateAlias (option, alias)](https://npmdoc.github.io/node-npmdoc-angular-cli/build/apidoc.html#apidoc.element.angular-cli.command.prototype.validateAlias)**

but I'm not sure why is taking "c" instead of "component".

Comment: None of this seems directly related to shell aliases, do you really need those tags?

Comment: which tags do you mean?

Comment: Just above the "share" and "edit" links (and I guess you see "delete") there are the tags [tag:angular] [tag:bash] [tag:shell] [tag:alias] but this seems to be only about [tag:angular] really.

Comment: the problem is that I don't know where this error come from. I think is something related with angular o npm but alias is from shell/bash so I can be sure ¿?

Comment: None of the commands you are running are producing errors from the shell or interacting with the shell beyond running a command at the shell prompt.

Comment: Googling the first error message gets me https://npmdoc.github.io/node-npmdoc-angular-cli/build/apidoc.html#apidoc.element.angular-cli.command.prototype.validateAlias

Comment: Same thing just started happening to me. It worked until recently and now just started complaining about this. Makes me wonder if it is some npm dependency used by the cli that got updated

Answer (score 3):

I don't know the root cause of this error, but this [commit](https://github.com/angular/devkit/commit/88a3e309e747835410ce7b909823fb263ca37d1c) changed a lot of aliases (including "c" for "component")...
If you change it locally in `node_modules/@schematics/angular/component/schema.json` to "cd", `ng generate` works again.

Note that when using `ng g component test` in a new project I don't reproduce this error. I'm using @nrwl/nx in the project that produces errors. The problem might lie in a version mismatch between ... I don't know what.

Answer (score 3):

I also dont know the cause of this error, but removing the explicitly installed `@schematics/angular` package solved it somehow:

```
npm uninstall @schematics/angular --save-dev
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks!!